# python autofill html data- expecting number but data type is string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to autofill html form data using python.  If I run the code without the autofill data, the webpage loads just fine.  But when I add the autofill data, I get:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not unicode
```

This is the code for the autofill data:

```
class EditCarHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
template_variables = {}

def get(self):

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/edit_cars.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(self.template_variables))

    carID = self.request.get('id')
    carData = Car.get_by_id(int(carID))

    colorArray = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    for i in carData.color:
        if i == "red":
            colorArray[0] = " checked"
        elif i == "orange":
            colorArray[1] = " checked"
        elif i == "yellow":
            colorArray[2] = " checked"
        elif i == "green":
            colorArray[3] = " checked"
        elif i == "blue":
            colorArray[4] = " checked"
        elif i == "purple":
            colorArray[5] = " checked"
        elif i == "black":
            colorArray[6] = " checked"
        elif i == "white":
            colorArray[7] = " checked"
        elif i == "gray":
            colorArray[8] = " checked"
        elif i == "other":
            colorArray[9] = " checked"

    conditionArray = ['', '', '']
    if carData.condition == "new":
        conditionArray[0] = " checked"
    elif carData.condition == "used":
        conditionArray[1] = " checked"
    elif carData.condition == "damaged":
        conditionArray[2] = " checked"


    self.response.write("""
    <main>
        <form action="/editCarsForm" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="%s">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Make:</legend>
                <input type="text" name="car-make" value="%s">
                <legend>Model:</legend>
                <input type="text" name="car-model" value="%s">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Year:</legend>
                <input type="number" name="car-year" min="1960" max="2016" value="%s">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Color:<legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="red"%s>Red
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="orange"%s>Orange
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="yellow"%s>Yellow
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="green"%s>Green
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="blue"%s>Blue
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="purple"%s>Purple
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="black"%s>Black
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="white"%s>White
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="gray"%s>Gray
                <input type="checkbox" name="car-color" value="other"%s>Other
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Condition:</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="car-condition" value="new"%s>New
                <input type="radio" name="car-condition" value="used"%s>Used
                <input type="radio" name="car-condition" value="damaged"%s>Damaged
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Today's Date:</legend>
                <input type="date" name="car-date" min="2016-01-01" max="2017-01-01" value="%s">
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Update Car">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_car">
        </form>
        <br>
        <form action="/viewCars" method="get">
            <button>View Cars</button>
        </form>
    </main>
    """ % (carID, carData.make, carData.model, carData.year, 
    colorArray[0], colorArray[1], colorArray[2], colorArray[3], colorArray[4], colorArray[5], colorArray[6], colorArray[7], colorArray[8], colorArray[9],
    conditionArray[0], conditionArray[1], conditionArray[2], 
    carData.date))
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: You have not included you Car model. My bet is the year property is not an integer property and your using %d as the format specifier.  The error message does tell you exactly what is going on.

Comment: No he has an input for car model, but not one for carID. When he get's that one in he'll need to convert it as well (or maybe not). But yea the year doesn't match up with the variable he's trying to put it into.

Comment: HUh `carID = self.request.get('id')
    carData = Car.get_by_id(int(carID))`  - this could be a string id, or needs to be converted to an int for an auto generated id, but that is not the cause of the error as per the question.  There are so many other problems with this code and code in previous questions, but are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: It works if i take out everything except just the id `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="%d">` and use `carID` as the variable.  All of the other variables match with their respective inputs

Comment: So I got everything except the checkbox and radio buttons to work using `%s` - for example the date `<input type="date" name="car-date" min="2016-01-01" max="2017-01-01" value="%s">` - using `carData.date` as the variable.  I am having trouble with the checkbox and radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

I got it!  The error was in the logic of the carData.color, and also radio buttons are "checked", not "selected"